# Python change directory while keeping symlinks in the path

Tags: python, path

So i have a this path:
`/nfs/dust/atlas/user/jnitschk/CAF/StatisticTool/Output/frac_100ex_3_smooth_truth`

that i execute a script from and thus get that when i do `os.getcwd()`.

Now i need to change to the following path to execute some subprocesses from:

`/nfs/dust/atlas/user/jnitschk/CAF/StatisticTool/Output/frac_100ex_3_smooth_truth/Output/ranking_output_Truth_Smooth_ExpSmoothUnblinded_2_100ex_3_frac_obs`

However as the second `Output` in the path is just a symlink to the first this is what i get when i do `os.chdir(THE_LONG_PATH)` and then `os.getcwd()`:
`/nfs/dust/atlas/user/jnitschk/CAF/StatisticTool/Output/ranking_output_Truth_Smooth_ExpSmoothUnblinded_2_100ex_3_frac_obs`

Is there an easy way to get `chdir` to keep the full path including the intermediate symlinks?

Comment: *"this is what i get"* - from where? From `os.getcwd()`? The OS does not remember that for you unfortunately. You will have to remember the path in the program yourself.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli yes, `os.getcwd()` or in a subprocess that just does `echo $PWD`.

I am not 100% following the rest. If i am in the original path in the shell and `cd` to the second i end up straight in the second as seen by doing `pwd`. And more importantly doing `cd ../..` puts me into the  `frac_100ex_3_smooth_truth` path instead of `StatisticTool`.

Comment: That's because your shell keeps track of the path.

Comment: Tell us why you want os.getcwd() to report the "long" path, that is, what software component experiences what bad outcome due to the "short" path? Also, NFS is irrelevant here, right, it would happen the same on local FS? For example bash `pwd` and forking a `/bin/pwd` child may produce long and short responses in the same way on local filesystem.

Comment: There is code after the `os.chdir()` with `cd ../../ && python example.py`.

With the short path it executes `.../StatisticTool/example.py`. With the long it one does `.../StatisticTool/Output/frac_100ex_3_smooth_truth/example.py`.

I guess i just need to swap all of those calles to ones using the full path. I was hoping there was an easy way to just modify the `os.chdir()` so i wouldnt have to do that.

Comment: @J_H forgot to tag

Answer (score 0):

## problem summary

We have this pair of directories:

1. StatisticTool/Output/frac_100ex_3_smooth_truth/
2. StatisticTool/Output/frac_100ex_3_smooth_truth/Output/ranking_foo_obs/

If we `cd` to the first, `ls -l` will reveal
an `Output` `->` symlink pointing up two levels.
Therefore a subsequent getcwd() won't mention "frac_100ex_3_smooth_truth" and will simply output
StatisticTool/Output/ranking_foo_obs

Due to a code defect, a script attempts `cd ../../`
in hopes of finding example.py there.
Fatal error ensues when that script is not found.

---

## robust scripting

I have successfully run a bunch of scripts in production
which avoided hardcoded absolute pathnames and
tried to be forgiving about where we started.
That is, we started "close" to the desired spot,
started somewhere within the right tree,
and we need to flexibly locate the nearby
directory of interest.
Usually this is for convenience of humans
that typed "cd wherever" before running a command.

Assuming no `set -e` error checking is turned on,
it may be enough for a script to just blindly
try a few chdir's, like `cd StatisticTool`
or `cd ../Output`. Sending stderr to /dev/null might make sense.
A more sophisticated approach is to examine `$(shell pwd)`
output and conditionally go to the right place.

The final command in such a sequence should be "chdir or die!",
for example `cd ../Output || exit 1`.
Verify that end-users will see appropriate diagnostic message
if that doesn't succeed.

Notice that `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
will produce the right string
if your directory tree is checked in to version control.

---

## make

A Makefile can contain several "phony" targets,
which essentially defines several brief scripts or command aliases.

An attractive aspect of `make` is that commands it runs
may confidently assume they're `cd`'d to the directory
containing the Makefile.
If an end-user types `$ make -C some/where/  run_report`,
the mere fact that we found the makefile guarantees
the expected execution environment for the reporting commands.
Consider leveraging that in production, both for
reduced training cost and for reliability.